# URGENT: How to unlock e230 mercedes benz model

Tags: mercedes-benz

I have accidentally lock my mercedes benz with my key in it. Can anyone help me with it...

Comment: You have three options - 1. Go home and get the spare key, use that to unlock the car. 2. Smash a window. 3. Call a locksmith. Option 1 is obviously the best!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about DIY

Comment: Did someone really just ask this question?...